# Why does R dplyr filter function induces changes in non filtered rows?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a question relative to R dplyr filter function. I have a tibble data1 with several columns, and I would like to remove all rows where the the column "CODE_FRAIS" is filled with the code "CINT".
My code to do so is :

```
data1 <- data1 %>% filter(CODE_FRAIS != "CINT")
```

But doing so, the filtered table returns only 0 for all numeric columns. And I don't understand why. And it's driving me crazy. Especially because this methodology usually works fine. 
Does anyone has an idea of what is going on here (and please, other than those involving my intellect ^^) Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: can you please provide sample data?

Comment: Did you try:  data1 %>% dplyr::filter(CODE_FRAIS != "CINT")  , because there are likely to be several filter functions present in r additional to the dplyr one.

Comment: I just tried it, it does not change the result...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace the rows with 0. You can't have unbalanced tables, you can either replace these values or equate them with NA and then use `!is.na` to filter out.

```
data1$CODE_FRAIS=ifelse(data1$CODE_FRAIS=="CINT",0,data1$CODE_FRAIS)
```

Comment: Okay, actually it seems that the problem is not related to the filter function, but rather to the format of my numeric columns. It says numeric, it looks numeric, but it does not behave as numeric.

Comment: Hello ! Shivam Sarin , no so far the problems remains the same. I successfuly removed all the "CINT" rows by fitering another colum, and it worked fine. But I am still very curious about what is hapenning with code_frais column. Anyway thank you very much to all those who took some time to answer ! If I finally find out I will post it here !